# merge data from arrays of objects

Tags: javascript

This kind of question has many responses but I need an iterable way to solve this
I have this first array:

```
let students = [
  { name: 'person1', email: 'person1@gmail.com' },
  { name: 'person2', email: 'person2@gmail.com' }
]
```

And I have this second array:

```
let attendances = [
  { email: 'person1@gmail.com', attendance: true },
  { email: 'person2@gmail.com', attendance: false }
]
```

What I need is an array that will merge only the key attendance from the attendances array into the student array so the email will show once and not be repeated. What I have done so far is to use a function that will merge the data in case any other student has logged in, but its not working out.

```
  function mergeData(students, attendances) {
    let infoMerged = {}
    for(let i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
        if(infoMerged.students[i].name && infoMerged.students[i].email ) {
            infoMerged.attendances[i].attendance
        }
    }
    return infoMerged
  }
  console.log(mergeData('person3', true))
```

Comment: *but its not working out* **is not an adequate problem description**. Please add the desired result. Also you present a function that expects to be passed two arrays, and then call it with a `string` and a `boolean`?? That's not gonna work.

Comment: Also you create an empty `infoMerged` object, and then try to access properties `students` and `attendances` on it (which both it doesn't have obviously, since you just created it as an empty object). Also what exactly do you mean by *but I need an iterable way to solve this*?

Comment: By the looks of it, you lack the most basic understanding for how Objects and Functions work, so I'd suggest you take some basic JavaScript tutorial for programming beginners, which is not in scope for this site. Simply search Youtube for "Javascript beginner tutorial".

Comment: I don't understand your console.log. If it would have been using the both arrays as parameters I would have done something like: 

function mergeData(students, attendances) {
  return students.map(el => { return {...el, attendance: attendances.find(att => att.email === el.email)?.attendance ?? false}});
}

Answer (score 0):

```js
let students = [
  { name: 'person1', email: 'person1@gmail.com' },
  { name: 'person2', email: 'person2@gmail.com' }
]

let attendances = [
  { email: 'person1@gmail.com', attendance: true },
  { email: 'person2@gmail.com', attendance: false }
]

let data = Object.fromEntries(students.map(x => [x.email, x.name]).map(([k, v]) => [k, {name:v}]));
let res = [];
for (let value of attendances) {
  res.push(data[value.email]);
  res[res.length - 1]['attendance'] = value.attendance;
  res[res.length - 1]['email'] = value.email;
}

console.log(res)
```